# Remove/disable geofence from Google API client

Tags: android, google-api-client, geofencing, android-geofence

I was wondering of what's the best practice to remove/disable a Geofence from a Google API client. My first idea was to disable a geofence within the client, but it looks like we can only remove all the geofences or either add a list to the API client.

Does that mean if I reference a list of geofences, and if I want to disable one temporarily, I have to remove this one from my local list of Geofences, remove all geofences from Google API client and add this geofence list again to the client?

Answer (score 3):

To remove geofence just call [remove the geofence from `GeofencingApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html#removeGeofences%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) with list containing only 1 item.

To temporary disable: store geofence parameters somewhere in your app (e.g. in sqlite or Shared Preferences), then remove it from `GeofencingApi` and restore (re-enable) when needed via [addGeofences](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html#addGeofences%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.util.List%3Ccom.google.android.gms.location.Geofence%3E,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Comment: Yes the strategy is to keep reference of those geofences with shared preferences. Looks like I have to remove geofences from the Google Api Client by providing a list of requestIds (a list with one requestId in my case). I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet to remove the Geofence with Google Play Services version 8.4.0

```
if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    return;
}

try {
    ArrayList<String> geofencIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    geofencIds.add(mTaskModel.getTaskId());

    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, geofencIds)
   .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
           if (status.isSuccess())
               // Remove notifiation here 
        }
    });
} catch (SecurityException securityException) {
    ToastUtils.showLongToast(getActivity(), securityException.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but it may help others.

to remove a single geofence, you have to set a tag to that specific geofence, then when and from wherever you want to remove that geofence just pass that tag from geofence notification service (in simple as intent extraString data), get the tag (using `getIntent.getStringExtra`) and call a new `GeofencingClient geofencingClient;`

then call

```
geofencingClient.removeGeofences(tag)
 .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
             Toast.makeText(context,
                 "Location alter has been removed",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "can't remove location alter",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.v("myReceiver", "error ==> " + task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

like I'm removing the geofence from using broadcast receiver here.
Here tag is defined as `List<String> tag = new ArrayList<>();`
you have to add your desired geofence's tag you want to remove and all set this method will remove your desired geofence.